# Under what circumstances is $a^Txa=a^Tax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $a \in R^n$ and $x \in R^n$. $x \in R^n$ means $x$ is a $n*1$ vector.

Under what circumstances is $(a^Tx)a=(a^Ta)x$? When am I allowed to say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are vectors, so the equality implies that $a, x$ are parallel to each other. So 
$$\tag{1} a = cx \ \ \text{or }\ \ x =ca.$$
On the other hand, if $(1)$ holds, then (for example if $x = ca$)
$$a^T xa = a^T(ca) a = a^T a (ca) = a^T a x.$$

So to conclude: The stated equality holds if and only if $a, x$ are parallel to each other.

Comment: Cool, can you please explain further why $a,x$ are parallel, I did not quite undersand it yet!

Comment: You are saynig that $(a^T x) a = (a^Ta) x$, so (if $a\neq 0$) $x = ca$ for $c = \frac{a^Tx}{a^Ta}$. @DimitriC

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, if I had $a^Tx=b$ where $b \in R$ I can still apply what you wrote on your answer for the same reason?

Comment: What exactly do you want to apply in this case?@DimitriC

Comment: $a^Tx=b \implies a^Txa=ba \implies a^Tax=ba \implies |a|^2x=ba \implies x=\frac{ba}{|a|^2}$

Comment: You used $a^Tax = a^Tx a$, which is true only if $a$, $x$ are parallel to each other. @DimitriC